# Возврат значения в java

Tags: android, java

Всем привет. Есть функция

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        if (id==kamnedsoft_student_FirstAD) {
            return MyAD("Первое AD","ddsa",true);
        }

        if (id==kamnedsoft_student_secondAD) {
            return MyAD("Второе AD","ddsa",true);
        }
    }
```

Он выдает такую ошибку: This method must return a result of type. Если я уберу все if и тупо верну свое значение, то значение возвращается. Что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что у вас может ни один if не выполниться, и компилятор не знает, что возвращать в таком случае.

Comment: Точно( затупил